# how can I solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I created two class

but I have problem

when I press run it is showing me this error

```
----jGRASP exec: java client

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at client.main(client.java:7)

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException << I know what is this mean

but I do not know how can I  correct my code !

this is first class

```
class circle{
  private double radius;
  static int count=0;
    public circle(){
        radius=8.9;
    }
    public circle(double r){
        radius=r;
        count++;
    }
    public void setradius(double r){
        radius = r;
    }
    public double getradius(){
        return radius;
    }
    public double area (){
        double area1 = (radius*radius*(Math.PI));
        return area1;
    }
    public double circumference(){
        double circumference1 = (Math.PI)*radius;
        return circumference1;
    }
    public static double areas(double r){
        double area2 = (r*r*(Math.PI));
        return area2;
    }
}
```

and this is the second one

```
class client{

   public static void main (String args[]){
      circle array[] = new circle [10];
          for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
            array [i]= new circle (i++);
            System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "+ array[i].getradius()+"is" + array[i].area() + "and the circumference is" + array[i].circumference());
            System.out.println(circle.areas(35));
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pedromss one of the two Sysouts, I think

Comment: @pedromss line 7 in class client

Comment: use i insted of i++
because it increment value of i by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` twice in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    array [i]= new circle (i++);
```

The result is that you are trying to access a circle in your array which has not yet been initialized (all array contents point to `NULL` initially). I'm sure you mean to write

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    array [i]= new circle (i + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `i` in the `for` loop and when you initialise each circle:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    array [i]= new circle (i++);
```

When you go to output the circle you are then referring to an uninitialised array entry.

You need to remove one of these:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    array [i]= new circle (i+1);
    System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "+ array[i].getradius()+"is" + array[i].area() + "and the circumference is" + array[i].circumference());
    System.out.println(circle.areas(35));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be your solution:

```
class client{

   public static void main (String args[]) {
        circle c[] = new circle[10];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            c[i] = new circle(i + 1);
            System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "+ c[i].getradius()+"is" + c[i].area() + "and the circumference is" + c[i].circumference());
            System.out.println(c[i].areas(35));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: c[i] = new circle(i); << I want send 1 not 0 @VINAY

Comment: then plus one to each like `new circle(i + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Because this line is increasing the value of i by 1. And the row after is using the next position in the array which is empty.

```
array [i]= new circle (i++);
System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "+ array[i].getradius()+"is" + array[i].area() + "and the circumference is" + array[i].circumference());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  array [i]= new circle (i++);
```

you count i one up. But the next i value is null.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is with this line:**

```
array[i] = new circle(i++);
```

You are adding i + 1 again.

Just do this:

```
array[i] = new circle(i);
```

Comment: but i do not want to send 0 i want send 1 @edubriguenti

Comment: You need to create another variable then. Create a "k" variable. Do not use the i, because this one you are incrementing in the for loop.

Comment: oh I can not use it like this array[i] = new circle(i+1); ?! @edubriguenti

Comment: Yes, you can use this way.